# Zip element of a row and loop them

Tags: pandas, for-loop, zip, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,4,5,6,8],
                  '1.1':[5,6,4,8,9,6],
                  '2':[6,np.nan,3,7,8,4],
                  '2.1':[1,np.nan,3,8,7,3],
                  '3':[np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,6,np.nan],
                  '3.1':[np.nan,np.nan,6,np.nan,5,np.nan]})
```

Then I have removed NaN values:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.dropna()), 1)
```

- Issue 1

Now I want to take every 2 row values and put into couple. I am not sure about data type, but I need them in `[[,],[,]]`:

```
[[1.0, 5.0],[6.0, 1.0]]
[[2.0, 6.0]]
[[4.0, 4.0],[3.0, 3.0],[4.0, 6.0]]
[[5.0, 8.0],[7.0, 8.0]]
[[6.0, 9.0],[8.0, 7.0], [6.0, 5.0]]
[[8.0, 6.0],[4.0, 3.0]]
```

To do this `[[,],[,]]` for *one row* I tried:

```
list(zip([df[0][0],df[0][1]]))
```

or

```
list(zip(df[0][0],df[0][1]))
```

But failed.

- Issue 2

As it is small random data and my data is bigger I want to create a for loop to zip them. But I can not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you may just `apply` and `zip`+`iter`. Also, you may define a function and do whatever you want in it - including for loops. At this beginner stage it's fine, but bear in mind to always avoid for loops while working with pandas.

```
def f(s):
  s = iter(s)
  return list(map(list, (zip(s,s))))
df.apply(f)
```

---

```
0                [[1.0, 5.0], [6.0, 1.0]]
1                            [[2.0, 6.0]]
2    [[4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 6.0]]
3                [[5.0, 8.0], [7.0, 8.0]]
4    [[6.0, 9.0], [8.0, 7.0], [6.0, 5.0]]
5                [[8.0, 6.0], [4.0, 3.0]]
dtype: object
```

---

There are many good references. There are great books available online and video tutorials on youtube, but [SO is not really the place to recommend books/tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) for learning.

Comment: Looks perfect. (-:

Comment: Pardon. It is perfect. Ok, I will delete/edit my question and remove "P.S." part. Sorry again